# Running Ruby Script

Tags: ruby, bash, shell

Can someone help me out?

So I installed Ruby 2.4 on my PC via the RubyInstaller from https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/. I have Windows 10.
I've used Ruby 2.2 and this 2.4 version seems very different.

When I installed it, it created an MSYS2.exe and it now opens a bash shell.

I've not used a bash shell in a very long time (14+ years). I can navigate fine in it. But I receive the following error message when I try to run a ruby file:

```
$ ruby r1.rb
bash: ruby: command not found
```

I'm not sure how to run a ruby script on the bash shell from MSYS. I have added the C:\Ruby24-x64\bin to my environment variables. But I still get the same message.

I'd appreciate some assistance if possible. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to add information to your question about how you installed it. Did you use the .exe installer on the ruby website?

Comment: Yes I did. I used the .exe installer.

Comment: Have you tried running it in a regular CMD.EXE window?  That works just fine for me with the Ruby 2.4.1 installation.  Check with "ruby --version" before trying to run a script, one thing at a time.

Comment: This was a big help. I'd have never thought to use the cmd.exe window because 2.2.4 (the previous version I had) wouldn't allow that. I can run a script quite fine now. It's amazing. Thanks. For reference, I am running 2.4.1p111

Comment: Glad that worked for you.